# How can I choose the column with slice?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
#     a   b  c    d   e   
#     1   2  5    3   999 
#     2   4  2    4   2   
#     999 2  8    7   999  
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df
```

I want to pick the columns in the above `df` by using `df.iloc[:,[0:2,4]]`.  How to set the parameters in `df.iloc`?  I have been seen this question, but I can't find it out now!

What I expect is:
the `a b e` columns.

Comment: In this case `df.iloc[:, [0, 1, 4]]` will also work.  For more complex cases use @jezrael's soln.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
df = df.iloc[:,np.r_[0:2,4]]
print (df)
     a  b    e
0    1  2  999
1    2  4    2
2  999  2  999
```

Comment: yeah! I have been seen this !thanks a lot